# Windows Server 2008 R2 のローカルイントラネットの設定確認方法について

Tags: windows-server, active-directory

現在ドメインコントローラとして稼働している、Windows Server 2008 R2のローカルイントラネットの設定内容を確認したく色々と調べているのですが困っています。

目的は、「イントラネットのネットワークを自動的に検出する」という画面（ダイアログ？）に辿り着く術を知りたいのです。

というのも、そのサーバから比較的直近のGPOの情報をエクスポートしたところ、ローカルイントラネットの「サイト」という項目に、

1. ほかのゾーンに指定されていないローカル（イントラネット）のサイトをすべて含める
2. プロキシ サーバーを使用しないサイトをすべて含める
3. すべてのネットワーク パス（UNC）を含める

といった項目が「有効」として記載されているのですが、それらはどこからどう辿れば確認することができますか？

試しに自宅の仮想環境に検証用としてWindows Server 2008 R2を立ててみて、私が試した手段は以下になります。

1. 「グループ ポリシーの管理」を開く
2. グループポリシーオブジェクトに適当にポリシーを作成し、右クリック→編集へ
3. 「グループ ポリシー管理エディター」が開くので、ユーザーの構成→Windowsの設定→Internet Explorer のメンテナンス→セキュリティをクリック
4. セキュリティ ゾーンおよびコンテンツの規制をダブルクリック
5. Internet Explorer セキュリティ強化の構成というダイアログが出るので「続行」を選択
6. 現行のセキュリティ ゾーンとプライバシーの設定をインポートするというラジオボタンにチェックが入った状態で、「設定の変更」をクリック
7. セキュリティタブ→ローカルイントラネット選択→サイトを押下
8. 適当にWebサイトのURLを入力して「追加」をクリック…

と、自分で色々とググってみたりして予想していたのは、8の「追加」をクリックした段階で例のダイアログが登場する…と思っていたのですが普通に追加されて終わりました。即席で作っただけの自前環境ですので、どこかで何かしらの設定をしていることが前提になるのかわかりませんが、ちゃんとした環境（前述の、GPOをエクスポートした本番環境）の場合なら、どこかから確認することができますか？

ちなみに、IEのバージョンは本番環境、自宅検証環境ともに8です（IE 10以降はそもそもInternet Explorerのメンテナンスという項目自体がないようですね…）。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決できました。IEのセキュリティ構成をオフったらできました。質問に目を通してくださった方々、失礼致しました。